# Evaluate Topic Modelling on synthetic data

Tags: python, nlp, topic-model, lda, gensim

I try to find the **optimal number of topics on a synthetic corpus** (so a list of lists of tokens I generate using various parameters). I, therefore, **know the true number of topics** and the true topics distributions. I believe it is a good way to **test unsupervised methods**. The issue is that I completely fail to find the correct number of topics.

I am using NMF and LDA from gensim with c_v and u_mass coherence scores. It **should be easy game** to find the optimal number of topics so I do not use hyperparameters for tuning. I believe the issue is deeper than that.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/seaslug95/topicmodelling).

It is well documented. The script to run is 'myscript.py'. It uses functions in 'mymodule.py'. You just need to install gensim and pandas (see requirements.txt if needed).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Could you please clarify how you generate the synthetic data? I had a quick look at the code and I noticed that you generate token frequency using uniform distribution: I don't know if this is the problem but it's certainly not realistic. In a realistic topic modelling problem the fact that tokens follow a Zipf distrib might play a role.

Comment: Thanks Erwan it is the kind of comment I was hoping : I did not know Zipf's law. First topics are created: a topic is a prob distri of tokens (for ex with exponential distri topic_0 = 0.6*'a0'+0.2*'a1'+0.1*'a2'+...). Then docs are generated: a doc is a list of tokens. A doc depends on 2 things: tokens distri within topics (see ex above) and topics distri (for ex doc_0 is 0.7*topic_0+0.2*topic_1+0.1*topic_2). I tried uniform and/or expo distri for tokens distri (=topic distri) and topics distri (=doc distri) but without success. I will implement Zipf distri for tokens distri and see how it goes